# Когда из ConfigureServices нужно возвращать IServiceProvider?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

Немного не понял, в каких случаях из этого метода что-то нужно возвращать?

Comment: судя по справке ни в каких. Откуда предположение, что _нужно_?

Comment: В aurofac пример видел.

Comment: Вот пример: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html . Если я правильно понимаю, то это нужно делать в том случае, когда используется кастомный контейнер зависимостей и в случае использования стандартного, то вовзращать ничего не нужно?

Answer (score -1):

В общем, как я понял, когда используется альтернативный контейнер зависимостей, то необходимо все зависимости, которые были переданы в `ConfigureServices` в виде аргумента с типом `IServiceProvider` взять и поместить в новый контейнер, а затем его вернуть.